# What is the meaning of $\mathbb C$-linearizarion?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am reading this book: **Theory of Complex Function** by Reinhold Remmert.

I just started reading the Chapter about Complex differentiation and I don't undersand the definition (Chapter 1, page 47):
[image]

I understand the part about the derivative as a limit, which is commonly found in other text books, here there is an example: [Textbook](http://www.math.utah.edu/%7Eyplee/teaching/4200f18/Ch2_pages.pdf)

What I don't understand is the part about the $\mathbb C$-linearization, inside the red rectangle in the image above. If I apply this definition to the function $f(z)=z^2$, I know that $f_1(z)=2z$, so the $\mathbb C$-linearization should be
$$f(z) = c^2 +(z-c)(2z).$$
Thus
$$2z = \frac{z^2-c^2}{z-c}$$
which does not make sense to me.

**Edit, since the OP has no time to fix this:** the problem was the OP's unjustified belief that $f_1(z)=f'(z)$. In fact for $f(z)=z^2$ we have $f'=2z$ and $f_1=(f(z)-f(c))/(z-c)=z+c$. No problem, since there was never any reason to think that $f_1=f'$.

What I am missing here? Can anybody help to understand what $\mathbb C$-linearization means here?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: It looks like you think $f_1(z)=f'(z)$. No, that's only true for $z=c$.

Comment: But the $\mathbb C$-linearization says that $f(z) = f(c) + (z-c)f_1(z)$ for every $z\in D$. Sorry, I am not following.

Comment: well i'm not following you either. first please clarify: _are_ you trying to explain why $f_1(z)=f'(z)$? (That linearization shows that $f'(z)=f_1(z)+(z-c)f_1'(z)$, at best...)

Comment: I am trying to understand the given definition of $\mathbb C$-linearization. For real functions I know that $f(x)\approx f(a)+f′(a)(x−a)$ with $x,a\in \mathbb R$. But in this definition, why the author is writing $f(z) = f(c)+(z-c)f_1(z)$, where $f_1 (z) = f'(z)$? Maybe I am misunderstanding this definition in complex numbers.

Comment: you ask why the author is writing $f(z)=f(c)+(z-c)f_1(z)$  with $f'(z)=f_1(z)$. The answer is that the author never wrote that! It's simply not true that $f'(z)=f_1(z)$, and nobody every said otherwise

Comment: He did write that, I am not making that up. Here is a pic of page 47 of his book: https://www.geogebra.org/resource/tfkyh8we/K19OXyvvPwCISFl4/material-tfkyh8we.png

Comment: This is ridiculous. Look at that image. _circle_ where it says $f'(z)=f_1(z)$, then upload it again so we can all see this equation that so far is visible only to you.\

Comment: (Forget what I said about MVT - I'd read something wrong.

Comment: The part we were hoping to see was where it says $f_1(z)=f'(z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems possible I finally understand the confusion.

*If* the question is "Why are the complex and real cases different?" the answer is they are *not* different! Everything we're talking about here applies equally well to real-valued or complex-valued functions; the only difference is you happened to see one statement in one context and the other in another. (In fact in every case considered here the complex-valued case follows trivially from the real-valued case.)

(Note that the Mean Value Theorem *is* true for real-valued functions but not for complex-valued ones. That's how it happened in a comment that I misread you as saying something about MVT: you were asking about the difference between real and complex, and MVT is the only difference here that springs to mind).

We should change your "$a$" to "$c$" if we're going to compare the two.

> > **Prop 1.** $f(x)\approx f(c)+(x-c)f'(c)$ as $x\to c$.

> > **Prop 2.** $f(x)=f(c)+(x-c)f_1(x)$, where $f_1$
> > is continuous and satisfies $f_1(c)=f'(c)$.

You're wondering about the difference and why, in exactly what sense isn't totally clear to me, but I have some good conjectures. One difference is that Prop 2 is an equation, while Prop 1 is just an approximation (and in fact Prop 1 is too vague to be math until we specify exactly what we mean by $\approx$.)

And Prop 1 mentions $f'(c)=f_1(c)$, while it's $f_1(x)$ in Prop 2.

The two are nonetheless related. I can't *prove* anything about Prop 1 without the missing definitions, but in fact if we do get them straight we can show Prop 1 follows from Prop 2:

$f_1(x)\approx f_1(c)$ as $x\to c$, so Prop 2 shows $$\begin{align}f(x)&=f(c)+(x-c)f_1(x)
\\ &\approx f(c)+(x-c)f_1(c)
\\ &=f(c)+(x-c)f'(c), \end{align}$$precisely Prop 1.

Comment: Hi David. Sorry I was not very clear with my question. Yes, I am trying to understand the $\mathbb C$-linearization and why it is slightly different from the case of real functions. I think I am misunderstanding the defintion where it says that _$f$ is differentiable at $c$ if there exists $f_1$ continuous at $c$ and satisfies $f(z)= f(c) + (z-c)f_1(z)$ for every $z\in D$_. Then I was trying to apply it to the function $f(z)=z^2$. I know that $f'(z)=2z$ and is continuous $\forall z\in \mathbb C$.

Comment: "Yes, I am trying to understand the C-linearization and why it is slightly different from the case of real functions" **It is no different. It is the same.**

Comment: But why in Prop 2 we have $f_1(x)$ instead of $f_1(c)$? For the case $f(z)=z^2$, is it correct to write $f’(z) = f_1(z)= 2z$ for all $z$? What does the identity $2z = (z^2-c^2)/(z-c)$ mean in this case? (By the way, thanks for following up with this topic).

Comment: because if you take Prop 2 and change $f_1(x)$ to $f_2(c)$ it becomes false. Oh dear: If you actually think that $(z^2-c^2)?(z-c)=2z$ is an identity that explains why you're confused! Actually $(z^2-c^2)/(z-c)=z+c$.

Comment: Btw, to make this sort of thing work right you need to retract statements that turn out to be false, so we know whether you got it. Here you should clarify whether you're still claiming that that image contains the equation $f_1(z)=f'(z)$.

Comment: Hint: If you consider $f(z)=z^2$ and do the elementary algebra correctly you see that $f_1(z)=z+c$ while $f'(z)=2z$. Sure enough not equal - you really did just make up this notion that $f_1=f'$.

Comment: Oh my :( I was totally confused. I misinterpreted the last part where it says $\frac{df}{dz}(c) = f'(c) = f_1(c)$, thinking that it applies for every $z$. Now I understand and see that for $f(z)=z^2$ then $(z^2-c^2)/(z-c)$ is fact equal to $z+c$. Since $z+c$ is continuous then $f_1(c)=2c=f'(c)$. I really appreciate your help and patience. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: Fine. For future reference, you could have made it a lot quicker: when I say $f_1\ne f'$ you could either show me a proof of $f_1\ne f'$ or ask me for a proof of the inequality. What you should try not to do in the future is post an image claiming it contains an equation that is simply not there...